# MQ Channel has TLS1.2 configured but wants TLS1.0 (Local MQ on Windows 10)

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq, .net-4.7.2

I have a local installation where I have configured two channels. One server channel and one client channel:

```
DISPLAY CHANNEL (DEV.APP.SVRCONN)
     1 : DISPLAY CHANNEL (DEV.APP.SVRCONN)
AMQ8414I: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2021-11-29)                     ALTTIME(13.39.26)
   CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremq)                COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)                           DESCR( )
   DISCINT(0)                              HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
   MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER(app)                            MONCHL(QMGR)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH(ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER)            SSLPEER( )
   TRPTYPE(TCP)
AMQ8414I: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)                CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN)
   AFFINITY(PREFERRED)                     ALTDATE(2021-11-29)
   ALTTIME(15.50.25)                       CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremq)
   CLNTWGHT(0)                             COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)                           CONNAME(DESKTOP-ROH98N2(1414))
   DEFRECON(YES)                           DESCR( )
   HBINT(300)                              KAINT(AUTO)
   LOCLADDR( )                             MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MODENAME( )                             PASSWORD( )
   QMNAME(QM1)                             RCVDATA( )
   RCVEXIT( )                              SCYDATA( )
   SCYEXIT( )                              SENDDATA( )
   SENDEXIT( )                             SHARECNV(0)
   SSLCIPH(ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER)            SSLPEER( )
   TPNAME( )                               TRPTYPE(TCP)
   USERID( )
```

and I tested my SSL settings by using:
`AMQSSSLC -m QM1 -c DEV.APP.SVRCONN -x localhost -k "C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key" -l ibmwebspheremq -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`

which gives me:

```
Sample AMQSSSLC start
Connecting to queue manager QM1
Using the server connection channel DEV.APP.SVRCONN
on connection name localhost.
Using SSL CipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Using SSL key repository stem C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key
Certificate Label: ibmwebspheremq
No OCSP configuration specified.
Connection established to queue manager QM1
Sample AMQSSSLC end
```

So that seems to be working correctly.

Now I have created an sample C# application which tries to use the generated TAB file or uses windows certificate store to get the SSL certificate. In both cases I am getting this error:

```
AMQ9616E: The CipherSpec 'TLS 1.0 0xC00A, ...' proposed by remote host
'DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (192.168.122.50)' is not enabled.

EXPLANATION:
The SSL or TLS subsystem at the server end of a channel been configured in such
a way that it has rejected the CipherSpec proposed by an SSL or TLS client. 

This error most commonly occurs when the choice of acceptable CipherSpecs has
been limited in one of the following ways: 
(a) The server queue manager SSLFipsRequired attribute is set to YES and the
  channel is using a CipherSpec which is not FIPS-certified on the server. 
(b) The server queue manager EncryptionPolicySuiteB attribute has been set to a
  value other than NONE and the channel is using a CipherSpec which does not
  meet the server's configured Suite B security level. 
(c) The protocol used by the channel has been deprecated. Note that IBM may
  need to deprecate a protocol via product maintenance in response to a
  security vulnerability, for example SSLv3 and TLSv1 have been deprecated.
  Continued use of SSLv3 and/or TLSv1 protocols is not recommended but may be
  enabled by setting environment variable AMQ_SSL_V3_ENABLE=TRUE or
  AMQ_TLS_V1_ENABLE=TRUE as required. 
(d) The requested CipherSpec has been deprecated or disallowed by TLS 1.3. Note
  that IBM may need to deprecate a CipherSpec via product maintenance in
  response to a security vulnerability, for example RC4_MD5_US has been
  deprecated. Continued use of deprecated CipherSpecs is not recommended but
  may be enabled by setting environment variable
  AMQ_SSL_WEAK_CIPHER_ENABLE=<CipherSpec>. For example,
  AMQ_SSL_WEAK_CIPHER_ENABLE=RC4_MD5_US 
(e) The certificates in use are not acceptable in combination with the
  CipherSpec, for example the key signature algorithm (RSA or ECDSA) may not be
  supported by the negotiated CipherSpec, or the certificate's key size might
  be too short (some CipherSpecs mandate a minimum 2048-bit RSA key length). 
(f) The CipherSpec is for TLS 1.3 and TLS 1.3 is not enabled. To enable TLS 1.3
  set the INI variable AllowTLSV13=TRUE in the SSL stanza.
ACTION:
Analyse why the proposed CipherSpec was not enabled on the server. Alter the
client CipherSpec, or reconfigure the server to accept the proposed CipherSpec.
Restart the channel. 
----- amqccisa.c : 9165 -------------------------------------------------------
30/11/2021 07:25:29 - Process(10560.4) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(DESKTOP-ROH98N2) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.3.0) QMgr(QM1)
                      Time(2021-11-30T06:25:29.546Z)
                      CommentInsert1(????)
                      CommentInsert2(10560(9724))
                      CommentInsert3(DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (192.168.122.50))
                     
AMQ9999E: Channel '????' to host 'DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (192.168.122.50)' ended
abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 10560(9724) for channel '????'
ended abnormally. The host name is 'DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (192.168.122.50)'; in some
cases the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 630 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Which suggests that the server responds with an proposed TLS version of 1.0. I was looking up this issue and found out it could be the order of the cipherspecs in the windows group policy. But the IBM documentation and the Microsoft documentation suggests that `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` has a higher ranking than any TLS 1.0 Cipherspec. (see: IBM: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=cipherspecs-cipherspec-order-in-tls-handshake, see: Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1903)

I set the certifcate to 2048 bits:

[image: Certificate settings]

In the trace log I found this:
`402 - GSK_ERROR_NO_CIPHERS`

Which suggests that SSLv2 and/or SSLv3 is not enabled. (see: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-protect/8.1.9?topic=codes-global-security-kit-return). But it works with the `amqssslc` tool.

The server side log gives me this:

```
01/12/2021 07:09:18 - Process(8408.15) User(Wilko) Program(Unknown)
                      Host(DESKTOP-ROH98N2) Installation(    Installation1
)
                      VRMF(9.2.4.0)
                      Time(2021-12-01T06:09:18.674Z)
                      ArithInsert1(0) ArithInsert2(0)
                      CommentInsert1(DESKTOP-ROH98N2(1414))
                      CommentInsert2(TCP/IP)
                      CommentInsert3( (Exception))
                     
AMQ9202E: Remote host not available, retry later.

EXPLANATION:
The attempt to allocate a conversation using TCP/IP to host
'DESKTOP-ROH98N2(1414)' for channel  (Exception) was not successful. However
the error may be a transitory one and it may be possible to successfully
allocate a TCP/IP conversation later. 

In some cases the remote host cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Try the connection again later. If the failure persists, record the error
values and contact your systems administrator. The return code from TCP/IP is 0
(X'0'). The reason for the failure may be that this host cannot reach the
destination host. It may also be possible that the listening program at host
'DESKTOP-ROH98N2(1414)' was not running.  If this is the case, perform the
relevant operations to start the TCP/IP listening program, and try again.
----- IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection.ConnectSocket : 0 -------------------------------
```

To be complete my C# code for testing:

```cs
 public void createConnection_ClientDefinitionTable()
        {
            var mqSettings = new Hashtable
            {
                //{ MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES },
                ////{ MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "DESKTOP-ROH98N2" },
                ////{ MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414 },
                //{ MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, @"C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key" },
                //{ MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" },
                //{ MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "DEV.APP.SVRCONN" },
                //{ MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, "DESKTOP-ROH98N2(1414)" },
                //{ MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, "ibmwebspheremq" },
                //{ MQC.Manager }
            };

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQSSLKEYR", @"C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLLIB", @"C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\@ipcc");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCHLTAB", "AMQCLCHL.TAB");

            var queueManager = new MQQueueManager("QM1", mqSettings);
        }
```

And also the `.CMD` file which uses environment variables just like the C# example (the .CMD connects to the queuemanager)

```
SET MQSSLKEYR=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key
SET MQCHLLIB=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\@ipcc
SET MQCHLTAB=AMQCLCHL.TAB

AMQSSSLC -m QM1 -k "C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key" -l ibmwebspheremq
```

UPDATE: Got this to work for CCDT scenario and keyrepo scenario in unmanaged mode.

The use of the managed .NET client gives me errors. What I have done:

- Created an self-signed certificate with the key management tool.
- Exported the certificate to a .CER file and imported the certificate in the windows certificate store
- Set the friendly name to: ibmwebspheremq

```cs
  var location = string.Concat("*", Enum.GetName(typeof(CertificateLocation), keystoreSettings.WindowsCertificateLocation).ToUpper());

                settings = new Hashtable
                {
                    { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
                    { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, keystoreSettings.Server },
                    { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, keystoreSettings.Port },
                    { MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, location },
                    { MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, keystoreSettings.SslCipherSpecificiation },
                    { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, keystoreSettings.Channel },
                    { MQC.CERT_LABEL_PROPERTY, "ibmwebspheremq" }
                };
```

and ran my C# client. I am getting this error:

server-side:

```
08/12/2021 07:40:10 - Process(14060.1) User(Wilko) Program(t.net472.x86.exe)
                      Host(DESKTOP-ROH98N2) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.3.0)
                      Time(2021-12-08T06:40:10.760Z)
                      CommentInsert1(Windows 10 Professional x64 Edition, Build 19043 (MQ Windows (x64 platform) 32-bit))
                      CommentInsert2(C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1))
                      CommentInsert3(9.2.3.0 (p923-L210708.DE))
                     
AMQ6287I: IBM MQ V9.2.3.0 (p923-L210708.DE).

EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ system information: 
Host Info         :- Windows 10 Professional x64 Edition, Build 19043 (MQ
Windows (x64 platform) 32-bit) 
Installation      :- C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1) 
Version           :- 9.2.3.0 (p923-L210708.DE)
ACTION:
None. 
----- amqxeida.c : 6638 -------------------------------------------------------
08/12/2021 07:40:10 - Process(14060.1) User(Wilko) Program(t.net472.x86.exe)
                      Host(DESKTOP-ROH98N2) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.3.0)
                      Time(2021-12-08T06:40:10.757Z)
                      CommentInsert1(localhost(1414))
                      CommentInsert2(TCP/IP)
                      CommentInsert3( (Exception))
                     
AMQ9202E: Remote host not available, retry later.

EXPLANATION:
The attempt to allocate a conversation using TCP/IP to host 'localhost(1414)'
for channel  (Exception) was not successful. However the error may be a
transitory one and it may be possible to successfully allocate a TCP/IP
conversation later. 

In some cases the remote host cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Try the connection again later. If the failure persists, record the error
values and contact your systems administrator. The return code from TCP/IP is 0
(X'0'). The reason for the failure may be that this host cannot reach the
destination host. It may also be possible that the listening program at host
'localhost(1414)' was not running.  If this is the case, perform the relevant
operations to start the TCP/IP listening program, and try again. 
----- IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection.ConnectSocket : 0 -------------------------------
```

client-side:

```
08/12/2021 07:40:10 - Process(5116.8) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzmur0.exe)
                      Host(DESKTOP-ROH98N2) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.3.0) QMgr(QM1)
                      Time(2021-12-08T06:40:10.692Z)
                      CommentInsert1(Windows 10 Professional x64 Edition, Build 19043 (MQ Windows (x64 platform) 64-bit))
                      CommentInsert2(C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1))
                      CommentInsert3(9.2.3.0 (p923-L210708.DE))
                     
AMQ6287I: IBM MQ V9.2.3.0 (p923-L210708.DE).

EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ system information: 
Host Info         :- Windows 10 Professional x64 Edition, Build 19043 (MQ
Windows (x64 platform) 64-bit) 
Installation      :- C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ (Installation1) 
Version           :- 9.2.3.0 (p923-L210708.DE)
ACTION:
None. 
----- amqxeida.c : 6638 -------------------------------------------------------
08/12/2021 07:40:10 - Process(4940.16) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(DESKTOP-ROH98N2) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.3.0) QMgr(QM1)
                      Time(2021-12-08T06:40:10.692Z)
                      RemoteHost(127.0.0.1)
                      ArithInsert1(420)
                      CommentInsert1(????)
                      CommentInsert2(gsk_secure_soc_read)
                      CommentInsert3(DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (127.0.0.1))
                     
AMQ9665E: SSL connection closed by remote end of channel '????'.

EXPLANATION:
The SSL or TLS connection was closed by the remote host 'DESKTOP-ROH98N2
(127.0.0.1)' during the secure socket handshake. The channel is '????'; in some
cases its name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'. The channel did
not start.
ACTION:
Check the remote end of the channel for SSL and TLS errors. Fix them and
restart the channel. 
----- amqccisa.c : 11296 ------------------------------------------------------
08/12/2021 07:40:10 - Process(4940.16) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(DESKTOP-ROH98N2) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(9.2.3.0) QMgr(QM1)
                      Time(2021-12-08T06:40:10.692Z)
                      CommentInsert1(????)
                      CommentInsert2(4940(14176))
                      CommentInsert3(DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (127.0.0.1))
                     
AMQ9999E: Channel '????' to host 'DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (127.0.0.1)' ended
abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 4940(14176) for channel '????'
ended abnormally. The host name is 'DESKTOP-ROH98N2 (127.0.0.1)'; in some cases
the host name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide. 
----- amqrmrsa.c : 630 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Looks to me like your C# app is trying to negotiate TLS1.0 and the server is rejecting that. What version of .NET is your app built again? If v4.7 or higher, it will default to the highest TLS version is supported by your OS. If lower, you'll need to specify that TLS v1.2 is enabled.

Comment: I am using .NET framework 4.7.2

Comment: Can you try other TLS1.2 cipher-specs listed here? 
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=client-cipherspec-mappings-managed-net

Comment: FYI, if you DISPLAY CHSTATUS while your C application is connected, you can see exactly which protocol and cipherspec are in use.

Comment: @MoragHughson my application fails to create the `MQQueueManager` object because of the TLS issue, so i cannot use DISPLAY CHSTATUS because this is done within a milisecond or so

Comment: @NeilMoss I am using a TAB file, so then I need to change the cipherspec for the channels, I rather not want to do that because currently the IBM tooling confirms a correct SSL connection

Comment: I hacked the routine to constantly trying to connect to the QueueManager but `DISPLAY CHSTATUS(DEV.APP.SVRCONN)` gives me `AMQ8420I: Channel Status not found.`

Comment: What version of the MQ dll are you using for your C# program, is it also 9.2.3? Your invocation of amqssslc is not using the CCDT, do you get the same results if you set the MQCHLLIB/MQCHLTAB env variables and run it like this: `AMQSSSLC -m QM1 -k "C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key" -l ibmwebspheremq`?  Your code is setting things via env variables but you are still passing the empty hash table.  The client side should log to `mq data path\errors` folder as well,  does the AMQERR01.LOG  under that location contain anything?

Comment: @JoshMc Tested without empty hashtable, does not make any difference.

Comment: @JoshMc I have created an .CMD file where I set the MQ* environment variables. And that also gives me correct SSL connection (same message as described in my original post):

```
AMQSSSLC -m QM1 -k "C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key" -l ibmwebspheremq
Sample AMQSSSLC start
Connecting to queue manager QM1
No client connection information specified.
Using SSL key repository stem C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\ssl\key
Certificate Label: ibmwebspheremq
No OCSP configuration specified.
Connection established to queue manager QM1
Sample AMQSSSLC end
```

Comment: @JosMc Yes the logs tell me what I posted in my original post. Trying to connect with TSL 1.0 which is bad :)

Comment: What version of the MQ dll are you using for your C# program, is it also 9.2.3?  Can you please paste the client logs,  these should be under `C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\errors\AMQERR01.LOG` not `C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QM1\errors\AMQERR01.LOG` which you already pasted.  Can you also try with updating your CLNTCONN channel to use `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` to see if it makes at difference (you can leave the SVRCONN as is). Note you can create/alter CCDTs independent of the queue manager,  for example `SET MQCHLLIB=C:\temp`,
`SET MQCHLTAB=AMQCLCHL.TAB`, `runmqsc -n`

Comment: Hi - my comment was actually about your working C application - but no matter

Comment: @JoshMc: AMDMDNETSTD 9.2.4 is the DLL version

Comment: @JoshMc I have added the other log which gives me nothing more that it cannot connect throught TCP/IP and an exception for the 3rd parameter.

Comment: `amqmdnetstd.dll` works only in Managed mode,  to use  kdb you would need to run in unmanaged mode with `amqmdnet.dll`.  If you stick with manged mode you need to import the cert into the windows USER or SYSTEM key store.   You would then reference it via the hashtable setting `MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY` to either `*USER` or `*SYSTEM`.

Comment: @JoshMc it was a long time ago that I developed .NET framework application and I am so used to use Nuget packages that I forgot to reference the dll. Thanks that worked for me! I cannot refer to names in an answer so if you can please create this answer as the fix i will vote it for right answer.

Comment: Only the dll reference was the problem?

Comment: As far as I can determinate, yes. It is understandable, because the .NET standard client only supports TLS 1.0 so it is sending that no matter what chipherspec you define. It is very ugly default to an TLS version without warning or exception, but that is my opinion.

Comment: Created some more unittests to confirm that without SSL settings no connection could be made. So the issue was resolved by using the other dll @JoshMc

Comment: Since your SVRCONN has `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)` it means that the MQ Client must pass a cert.   Since you are using `amqmdnetstd.dll` and it only operates in Managed mode it means it can't use the kdb file that `amqssslc` uses.   Did you import a cert into your windows keystore?

Comment: @JoshMc I am aware of that and since you pointed me to the right direction, I changed the dll and used the unmanaged version. I might try to use the managed version in combination with the keystore but it still is not going to work for TLS 1.2 because it is currently not supported and the .NET standard lib defaults to TLS 1.0.

Comment: The .net standard version should work fine with tls1.2, the problem is managed mode can't access a kdb keystore.   It must be the windows USER or SYSTEM cert store.  IBM deprecated and disabled TLS1.0 long before the .NET standard version was released. Managed mode uses the cipher specified on the channel as a hint of what TLS version to use.   I think it may just not be properly picking up the ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER value (this is new in 9.2) and this is why I suggested you try it with TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 in your CCDT. I know manged mode works with that value.

Comment: @JoshMc I am now testing the windows cert store option with the .NET framework version. If i get it to work i will try the same with the .NET standard version. Currently I have put the certificate in the store and I can get an connection but somehow it is proposing TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 while i set TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

Comment: It only uses what you set as a hint,  in this case TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 is a TLS1.2 cipher,  it negotiated to the best TLS1 2 cipher between what the client and server support which in this case is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384.  This is normal behavior for managed mode and is unique to. Net managed mode.

Comment: I cannot get it work with the windows certificate store. I used the same certificate as in the solution with the CCDT and the solution with SSL keyrepository. But I am getting error: AMQ9665 when trying to use windows key store. @JoshMc

Comment: You should add the full error in the question by editing it.

Comment: Try to either blank or the CERTLABL on the CLNTCONN  or import the full cert and private key into the windows key store.

Comment: @JoshMc I tried blanking the CERTLABL on the client connection. Did not change anything, no difference in error, also removed it from the call from C# and still no change. Now I am going to import full certificate and private key (I thought I have done this already but i will check again)

Comment: I have a self-signed certifcate and client and server are running on same machine, how do I have to import private key? @JoshMc

Comment: I suggest exporting the cert from the  kdb to a pkcs12, name it with a `.pfx`  extension then double click, windows should prompt you to import it.

Comment: Okay, after importing the pfx  now also there is an extra machine key in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` . Unfortunately no change, same errors in logs.